# Remove strings after special characters - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My input Table is like this:

```
 PARSED_VALUE2        |   PARSED_VALUE4
 ---------------------|---------------
 CHIN     CONTACT     |  CHIN     CONTACT
 ---------------------|----------------
 HAMLET / PH          |  HAMLET / PH
----------------------|---------------
 NameM(               |  NameM(
----------------------|----------------
```

The output I want is like this:

```
       PARSED_VALUE   |   PARSED_VALUE4
 ---------------------|---------------
 CHIN        CONTACT  | CHIN 
 ---------------------|----------------
 HAMLET / PH          | HAMLET
----------------------|---------------
 NameM(               | NameM
----------------------|----------------
```

However, I'm getting the output as:

```
 The output I want is like this:

       PARSED_VALUE   |   PARSED_VALUE4
 ---------------------|---------------
 CHIN        CONTACT  | CHIN 
 ---------------------|----------------
 HAMLET / PH          | HAMLET / PH
----------------------|---------------
 NameM(               | NameM(
----------------------|----------------
```

This is the code I have written:

```
SELECT *
       , COALESCE(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%' + '/' + '%',PARSED_VALUE2) >=1 
                       THEN left(PARSED_VALUE2,CHARINDEX('/', PARSED_VALUE2)-1) 
                       ELSE PARSED_VALUE2 END   --HAMLET / PH
       , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%' + 'CONTACT' + '%',PARSED_VALUE2) >=1 
              THEN left(PARSED_VALUE2,CHARINDEX('CONTACT', PARSED_VALUE2)-1) 
              ELSE PARSED_VALUE2 END
       , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%' + '(' + '%',PARSED_VALUE2) >=1 
              THEN left(PARSED_VALUE2,CHARINDEX('(', PARSED_VALUE2)-1) 
              ELSE PARSED_VALUE2 END) PARSED_VALUE4 
  FROM #TEMPP
```

However, I'm not getting the desired result. What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH cte(PARSED_VALUE2)
AS
(
SELECT 'CHIN     CONTACT'UNION ALL
SELECT 'HAMLET / PH'     UNION ALL
SELECT 'NameM('          
)
SELECT PARSED_VALUE2,
      SUBSTRING(PARSED_VALUE2,0,PATINDEX('%[/( ]%',PARSED_VALUE2)) AS PARSED_VALUE4 
FROM cte
```

Result

```
PARSED_VALUE2       PARSED_VALUE4
-------------------------------------
CHIN     CONTACT    CHIN
HAMLET / PH         HAMLET
NameM(              NameM
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have 1mn records like this and Actually, PARSED_VALUE2 is a name and in few cases the name has surname. Hence, I want only the special chars to be removed keeping the surname (that is  A-Z or a-z) as is. In the above query its removing the surname as well. Any other alternative?

Comment: i written code as per the sample data which you provided

Answer (score 1):

I suggest get the index of the first special character using PATINDEX, then use LEFT (index - 1) to get the data you need.

```
SELECT LEFT(PARSED_VALUE2, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', PARSED_VALUE2) - 1)
FROM #TEMPP
```

Comment: Error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.  Note: For few records, there are no blanks between alphabets and special chars [for example  XYZ/ or AQQ( ]. Those things are not getting removed.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Try "SELECT LEFT('XYZ/', PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', 'XYZ/') - 1)" and it will result to XYZ.